# Symfony 1.4 validator

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, customvalidator

I have a problem with symfony 1.4 validator

I wanted to write my own validator, but I have a little problem.

My error message is the same as the value in the configuration of the form

My code

```
class sfValidatorDefaultString extends sfValidatorString{

  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);

    $this->addMessage('default_string', 'Error message');

    $this->addOption('default_string');
  }
  protected function doClean($value)
  {
    $clean = parent::doClean($value);

    // tutaj utknąłem 
    if(in_array($value, $this->getOptions('default_string')))
    {
         throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'default_string', array('value' => $value['name'], 'default_string' => $this->getOption('default_string')));
    }

    return $clean;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your problem .. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: 'ContactForm

'name'       => new sfValidatorDefaultString(array(), array( 'default_string' => 'name')),
'
When the user write in the input'name' name he schould have error : 'Error message' but now he will have  error : 'name'

Comment: Another how can I use $this->addMessage('default_string', '**Error message**');    
in    throw new sfValidatorError($this, '**here**'

Comment: Edit your question to have relevant code more highlighted

Answer (score 0):

When you got an error on a form, you always have the related widget (here `name`) and the error message for this widget (here `Error message`).

How do you display errors in your template? Using a custom way or the usual one (with `<?php echo $form ?>`)?

For the `addMessage` and `sfValidatorError`, when symfony throw a `sfValidatorError` the second parameter is the error code. It will try to find a message for this error code, which you well defined in your configure:

```
$this->addMessage('default_string', 'Error message');
```